# Conexion Visual Studio 2015 con MySQL 5.6

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un inconveniente y es que necesito realizar una aplicacion web utilizando c sharp y el IDE Visual Studio 2015 profesional enlazado con el motor de bd MySQL , para lo cual instale esta version que incluye el connector.net (6.9.9) , workbeanch y mysql(5.6).  (mysql-installer-community-5.6.12.0). Mi sistema operativo es win 8 de 64 bits

Mi pregunta es como hacer para realizar la coneccion entre VS y MySQL ya que  agregue referencias (mysql.data) por nugets package y nada, no me sirve. No sale error pero cuando intento realizar la conexion con el provedor de base de datos no me aparece MySQL tal y como se observa en la imagen.

Por favor, si alguien me puede ayudar les agradezco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Instalaste este [conector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)

Comment: si claro instale el conector

Comment: si claro instale el conector y ahora probe apareciendo el siguiente error .... https://www.google.com.co/search?q=error+mysql+visual+studio+2015&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYuI3h9erTAhWOdSYKHQgyDx4Q_AUICygC&biw=1366&bih=662#tbm=isch&q=error+entity+mysql+visual+studio+2015&imgrc=AniaKcBhiT3QDM: